# Django easy_pdf remove margin

Tags: python, css, django, python-3.x, django-templates

To create pdf from html i use [`easy_pdf`](https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) with is connected to [xhtml2pdf](http://fwpn.org.pl/assets/event_attachments/asd.html).

Small example:

in view.py

```
from easy_pdf.rendering import render_to_pdf_response

context = dict({'user_company': 'test'})
template_name = "pdf_template.html"
return render_to_pdf_response(request, template_name, context)
```

html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
          }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {{user_company}}
    <img src="/static/some_image.png" height="1000" width="1000">
</body>
</html>
```

Image and all element are placed inside margins:

[image]

I have try to change and add some margins options inside `side_packages/easy_pdf/templates/easy_pdf/base.html` : [github link](https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf/blob/master/easy_pdf/templates/easy_pdf/base.html)

```
        <style type="text/css">
            @page {

                // added
                margin: 0 !important;

                * {
                    margin: 0 !important;
                    padding: 0 !important;
                }

                body {
                   margin: 0 !important;
                   padding: 0 !important;
                }


                @frame {
                   margin: 0 !important;
                }

                // changed
                size: {{ pagesize|default:"A4" }};
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                margin-top: 0;
                margin-bottom: 0;

                @frame header {
                    -pdf-frame-content: page-header;
                    margin-top: 0;
                    margin-right: 0;
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    margin-left: 0;
                }

                @frame footer {
                    -pdf-frame-content: page-footer;
                    bottom: 0;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    margin-right: 0;
                    height: 0;
                }
            }
        </style>
```

But without effect

**Question**

Where to add or change css options to remove the margins from pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

you need to add below into you template style:

```
<style>
    @page {
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        }
</style>
```